# C# Windows Service can't access to network drive

Tags: c#, service, network-share

My Service is LocalSystem (can't be used user, because it must run on server)

If I use:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"\\10.0.20.1\Public\fld\file.txt", "Text");
```

I get this exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The user name or password is incorrect.

I tried class from [Simple-access-to-network-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)

```
using (NetworkShareAccesser.Access("10.0.20.1", @"ABC\\", @"ABC\\User123", "Password"))
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"\\10.0.20.1\Public\fld\file.txt", "Text");
}
```

But I got exception "The specified username is invalid".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: No... I'm not on domain.

Comment: That makes things more "fun".

Comment: Shouldn't you be using @"ABC\User123" instead of @"ABC\\User123"?  No need to escape the \ since you are using the @ prefix on the string literal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550742/how-can-i-give-a-windows-service-access-on-a-remote-machine-in-case-of-workgroup